# Stacking line drawing for float images in Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I am using a float image to draw some lines.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

im = Image.new("F", (64, 64), 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.line((0, 0, 64, 64), 128, 5)
draw.line((0, 64, 64, 0), 128, 5)
im.show()
```

[image: wrong result]

However, it does not stack lines one over the other. I would like to have a result where the value is added from both line drawing.

[image: expected result]

I tried to add_modulo two float images

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageChops
im1 = Image.new("F", (64, 64), 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im1)
draw.line((0, 0, 64, 64), 128, 5)

im2 = Image.new("F", (64, 64), 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im2)
draw.line((0, 64, 64, 0), 128, 5)

im = ImageChops.add_modulo(im1, im2)
```

but Pillow is raising a `ValueError: image has wrong mode` (and that would be inefficient for a lot of lines).

Is there a way to do that other than iterating on two images to do the addition of pixels ?

*Edit:*
It seems `scikit-image` suffer the same issue, so I would also accept any solution involving it.

Comment: Is there any requirement to use PIL? If not, I recommend a higher level library like [pycairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/)

Comment: I would prefer a python 3 compatible library, without external libraries dependencies (other than scientific libraries (numpy, scipy, ...))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate coordinates and values using the draw module, and then
add them to the image (which is just a standard numpy array):

```
from skimage.draw import line_aa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

image = np.zeros((64, 64), dtype=float)

for (rr, cc, val) in [line_aa(0, 0, 63, 63),
                      line_aa(63, 0, 0, 63)]:
    image[rr, cc] += val

image /= image.max()

plt.imsave("/tmp/out.png", image, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap='gray')
```

If you need to draw wider lines, we have such functionality although it is currently a bit hidden in the `measure` submodule.  I'd be glad to expose that in the drawing module if you find it useful.

Comment: Ok, It seems I did not understand what line_aa returns :-)
I see you are dividing your image by the max, is it to normalize between -1 and 1 (for float images) ? If so, can you explain why this restriction on float images ?

Comment: Float images are defined to have values between 0 and 1 (or -1 and 1 for signed images)--please see the user guide (http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.10.x/) for a more detailed description.

Comment: @Stefan - yes, yes, yes.  please add line widths to the draw module APIs.  It is sadly lacking.  It's now 2019,  I had a look in the measure module and all I can see is `profile_line()` which has a `linewidth` parameter.  Is this what you were referring to re "currently a bit hidden in the measure submodule" ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [cairo graphics library](http://cairographics.org/) and its [Python bindings](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/) instead of Pillow. It allows you to [set](http://cairographics.org/documentation/pycairo/2/reference/context.html#cairo.Context.set_operator) the [compositing operator](http://cairographics.org/documentation/pycairo/2/reference/constants.html#constants-operator).

Create an [`ImageSurface`](http://cairographics.org/documentation/pycairo/2/reference/surfaces.html#class-imagesurface-surface), if you want a bitmapped image. You can write that to a PNG file with the [`write_to_png`](http://cairographics.org/documentation/pycairo/2/reference/surfaces.html#cairo.Surface.write_to_png) method.